# Reading only "Not Deleted" records into a dataframe from a DBF file

Tags: python, dbf

I am using dbfread package to read DBF files and process them to a dataframe:

```
from dbfread import DBF
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
arcust = DBF('arcust.dbf',ignore_missing_memofile=True)
arcust = DataFrame(iter(arcust))
```

However, the DBF has a lot of records that are marked as deleted that I would not like to load to my dataframe.

How can I use .deleted() attribute of dbfread to only exclude deleted records from loading to the dataframe? Or, is there a better way or a different package to use to exclude deleted records from loading to the dataframe?

Comment: based od documentation: if you use `load=True` then it created lists `records` and `deleted` - so you could use `records` to create `DataFrame`

Comment: if you digg in [source code](https://github.com/olemb/dbfread/blob/master/dbfread/dbf.py#L181) then you see that it loads `self._records = list(self._iter_records(b' '))` and `self._deleted = list(self._iter_records(b'*'))` and you could use this information to skip deleted.

Comment: based on source code it seems you should simply use `arcust.records` to skip deleted.